# Why doesn't Xcode install my iOS app after using CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, xcode4, cocoapods

I have installed CocoaPods, and placed my dependencies in the Podfile. After running `pod install`, I open the myproject.xcworkspace which shows a `Pods` project and a `MyProject` project.

When I click run like I normally do, though, Xcode simply says "Build Succeeded" instead of installing the app to my device. What am I missing here?

**Short version: How do you get Xcode to install an app to device after opening your CocoaPods workspace?**

Comment: I don't use CocoaPods yet, but which scheme do you have selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your active scheme is your application scheme and not CocoaPods `Pod` scheme.  In the drop-down to select schemes choose your application.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this but saw some errors and assumed that wasn't the right solution. The errors ended up being because I never #import -ed the right libraries into my .m files.